# javascript - Open device's default sttings app and/or wifi settings

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, wifi

I want to make a wifi checker for my website, and want to make a link/javascript function that opens the users device default settings app. Does anyone know how?

**Example:** do you know when an app detects you need like: a pair of headphones, or bluetooth controller, It'll give you a button for "bluetooth settings"

Comment: Which JavaScript based app are you thinking of?

Comment: It's my parking game, it's actually a site. I made the wifi checker already, I just need the link for wifi settings.